# Windows phone:access subproperty of binding

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a custom pivot control where all the UI is generated using template.It looks like this:

```
<controls:Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding superSets}">
    <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedNews}}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <!- datatemplate Code -->
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
        </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot>
```

Now,I want to sort the contents of listbox so I designed a collectionviewsource like this:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedNews" Source="{Binding Path=Articles}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Pubdate"></scm:SortDescription>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

About the `superSets`:
It contains an Observable collection type property `Articles`

Now when I run the program I get an error saying `Property 'Articles' not found`

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that you defined the CollectionViewSource in the Resource of the page, you need to define it inside the ItemTemplate (Wrap the ListBox by a grid and define the CollectionViewSource in the Resource of the Grid).

```
<controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
          <Grid.Resources>
             <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedNews" Source="{Binding Path=Articles}">
                 <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Pubdate"></scm:SortDescription>
                 </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
             </CollectionViewSource>
           </Grid.Resources>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedNews}}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                       <!- datatemplate Code -->
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Yeah,I'm too thinking that it's the problem.But I don't know how to code the CollectionViewSource thing inside ItemTemplate.